# Php calendar of events

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I have calendar of events that pulls data from MySQL and with PHP to display it on a page. Now the client wants that when people open the page it slides to the next upcoming event. Past dates stay but slide to next upcoming event.

Here is live example: http://www.sv-filipjakov.hr/en/calendar-events.

Here is date code:

```
<article class="KalendarDogadjanjaBox KalendarCrveni">
    <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxDatum">
        <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxDatum1">21. June</div>
        <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxDatum2"> 09h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxOpis">
        <h3>World music day, Sv. Filip i Jakov</h3>
        <p>:)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
```

Maybe to but date I data attribute of article, format it, and then slide with jQuery? Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: as far as I can tell this really has nothing to do with php or mysql, you will need to build this in jquery also your date isn't linked anywhere on that page so like your page is now you won't be able to do that, what you could do is put your dates in a hidden input in your div's and use jquery to focus on the div that has the input with the closest date to the current date

Comment: I will try to add data as id of article, an get next date from base, format id to id and scroll to id by jquery.

Comment: that sounds like it will probably work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I add a date as id to article:

```
    <article id="23-05-15" class="KalendarDogadjanjaBox ">
      <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxDatum">
        <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxDatum1">23. May</div>
        <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxDatum2">23.-31.05 h</div>
      </div>
      <div class="KalendarDogadjanjaBoxOpis">
                  <a class="right" style=" position:relative; top:10px; right:-20px;" href="/slike/18052015_6377721205.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[100]" title="Izložba radova 8.Likovne kolonije  „Svibanj 2015“"><img style="width:130px; height:100px;" src="/slike/male/18052015_6377721205.jpg"> </a>
                <h3>Izložba radova 8.Likovne kolonije  „Svibanj 2015“</h3>
        <p>Likovna kolonija Maj 2015 Turanj , okuplja umjetnike iz društava Slovenaca „Triglav“ iz Splita, „Istra“ iz Pule, Slovenski dom iz Karlovca, Slovenski dom iz Zagreba , „Bazovica“ iz Rijeke, i  „Lipa“ iz Zadra,  a pridružuju im se i likovni umjetnici iz Zadra i Sv. Filip i Jakova, Turnja i Zagreba.<br />
Svoje sudjelovanje na likovnoj koloniji potvrdili  su i slikari  umjetnici  iz Sežane i Dolenjskih toplic  iz Slovenije.</p>
      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </article>
```

and create php function to call upcoming event:

```
<?php 
function KalendarSlideTo(){
global $link;
$rezultat = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM kalendar_dogadjanja WHERE KalendarDatum >= '".date('Y-m-d')."' LIMIT 1");
$redak = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat);
echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($redak['KalendarDatum']));
}?>
```

and this jquery code:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    'scrollTop':   $('#<?php KalendarSlideTo(); ?>').offset().top
}, 1);
```